# Encountering critical error after using scanf to enter a number

Tags: c, loops

Okay I am coding in C and using Codeblocks. I am trying to use the taylor series to calculate sinh(x) to practice loops. My program runs but after I enter a number it runs into a critical error and crashes.

I am fairly certain my error occurs somewhere in the assigning of a valuethrough the use of a pointer at the first scanf line in the getInput function, these lines in question being:

```
        printf ("please enter the value of x\n");
        scanf ("%lf", *xPtr);
        printf ("please enter the number of terms you would like to use\n");
        scanf ("%lf", *nPtr);
```

The whole of my mess of a code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//Global declerations
double x, *xPtr = &x; //declares variable x and the x pointer
double n, *nPtr = &n; //declares variable n and the n pointer

//Function protypes
void getInput ();
double sinHyper ();


/*-------------------------------------------------------------
function: main
Description: calls the funtion getInput to get the input values, the
        value of x and the number of terms (n), from the user.
        main then calls calls the function sinHyper to compute
        the value of sinh(x)

---------------------------------------------------------------*/
void main (shx)
{
  // variable declarations

 getInput();
 double sinhx, *sinhxPtr;

 *sinhxPtr = shx;
 printf("sinh(%.6e)\n", *sinhxPtr);

}

void getInput (void)
{

  printf ("please enter the value of x\n");
  scanf ("%lf", *xPtr);
  printf ("please enter the number of terms you would like to use\n");
  scanf ("%lf", *nPtr);
  while  (*nPtr <= 0 ) {
    printf ("please enter make sure to use at least 1 term(s) for the computation of sinhx \n");
    scanf ("%lf", *nPtr);
  }
}


double sinHyper ()
{
    double shx, *shxPtr = &shx;
    double i;
    i = 1;
    double priorTerm, *pTPtr;   //pTPtr = PriorTermPointer
    pTPtr = &priorTerm;

    do
    {
        if ( i == *nPtr )
            *shxPtr = *xPtr;
        else
            {
            *pTPtr = *xPtr;
            *pTPtr = ((pow((*xPtr), 2))/((2*i+1)*2*i))+(*pTPtr);
                i = i + 1;

                if (i != *nPtr)
                {
                  *pTPtr = ((pow((*xPtr), 2))/((2*i+1)*2*i))+(*pTPtr);
                  i = i + 1;
                }

            }
    }
    while ( i != *nPtr );
    if (*nPtr == 1)
      return shx;

    else
      *shxPtr = *pTPtr;
    return shx;

}
```

Comment: scanf() requires you to pass a pointer to the variable.  So use xPtr or &x, not *xPtr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scanf requires you to send the address to where the data will be saved, for example:

```
int x;
scanf("%d", &x); // save to address of x
```

In your example, you need to send either the adress of x, or the pointer (which saves the address of x)

Answer (score 0):

Hang on, just a thought, did you try removing the extra '*' in your scanf statement for the arguments? So for instance, instead of scanf("%lf", *something)  you use
scanf("%lf", something).

Scanf expects an address but what you seem to be doing is giving it a 'value' instead of an address. That's what adding the * to a pointer does. That expression * on a pointer variable means it is now a value and not an address. The address itself is the pointer variable name which you initialized. So just use the pointer variable without the preceding asterix (*) and see if that works.